# Call Java Web-Service with Ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, web-services

I am a newbie in Web-Services and ajax.

I am looking for a good step by step tutorial to call a Web-Service (I made one in Java) on a website. I thing that works with Ajax.
(with code examples)

I searched a lot but i found nothing.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by Web Service (SOAP or REST) but anyway...

First, I suggest you to read up on Ajax on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/AJAX).

However, just to give you a preview, you would do something similar to:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', yourWebServiceURL, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if ( xhr.status == 200 ) { 
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }
}
xhr.send(params);
```

where `yourWebServiceURL` is, well, your Web Service URL, `xhr.responseText` is the server's response and `params` are your POST params.